# Pinescript: bar_index / visible bar calculations not performing as intended

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm working on an indicator that uses the built-in `ta.VWAP` function. This function requires that the user supply a boolean input that when `true` triggers `ta.VWAP` to begin calculating on the trigger bar. In the following example, when `startTime` is `true` VWAP begins calculating on the left most visible bar on the chart:

```
var int leftBarIndex    = na
if time == chart.left_visible_bar_time
    leftBarIndex := bar_index
startTime            = bar_index == leftBarIndex ? true : false
[vwap, upper, lower] = ta.vwap(src, startTime, stdevMult)
```

This works perfectly.

However, the goal is to anchor VWAP to a bar that is x% of the distance between the left and right most visible bars. If X is 25% and there are 100 bars visible on the chart, then VWAP should anchor on the 25th bar from the left. Thanks to pinecoders https://www.tradingview.com/script/j7vCseM2-VisibleChart/, the code exists to do this:

```
var int leftBarIndex    = na
var int rightBarIndex   = na
var int diff            = na
var int diff2           = na
var int anchorX         = na

if time == chart.left_visible_bar_time
    leftBarIndex := bar_index                     // Identify left most visible bar
if time == chart.right_visible_bar_time
    rightBarIndex := bar_index                    // Identify right most visible bar

diff        := rightBarIndex - leftBarIndex       // total # of bars visible on the chart
diff2       := int(diff/4)                        // 25% of the visible bars
anchorX     := leftBarIndex + diff2               // anchorX is now the bar_index 25% from the left side of the chart
startTime   = bar_index == anchorX ? true : false // trigger VWAP to initiate when bar_index = anchorX
```

I've plotted all the calculated variables and confirmed that they are calculated correctly and are integers, but VWAP does not plot. By way of troubleshooting, it works perfectly if I take the confirmed value of anchorX and use that to replace anchorX in the last line. For example:

```
int xyz     = 3100
startTime   = bar_index == xyz ? true : false
```

produces a VWAP that anchors to bar 3100.

Bottom line: it's very clear that the calculations are correct and the code does what is expected, EXCEPT for the fact that in the last line bar_index is not being treated as identical to anchorX, even though it is mathematically identical. It's seems as if there is some sort of mismatch in variable types but as a nubi I have not been able to sort this out. I've tried versions where every imaginable calculation involving relevant integers are wrapped in int() but that didn't help.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: without the complete code it is hard to test on our side and help you.

Comment: It's essentially complete. Take the 2nd/larger box of code above, put an indicator call at the top and the following 2 lines at the bottom:  `[vwap, upper, lower] = ta.vwap(hlc3, startTime, 1)`.     `plot(vwap)`.

Comment: As you want. Without the complete code I can't test it and help you.

Comment: ??? I said you now have the complete code. Just add the 2 lines in the comment above to the bottom and include it under the call statement that pine script automatically provides when you create a new indicator